# Leaflet array of markers that need to move not recreate

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet

Firstly - I am a novice who has picked away at getting something functional for me over the past few years. My code below basically works - it's just complex and I believe there must be a better approach. Looking for a kick in different direction.

I am using javascript and leaflet to display an array of moving markers (players). The data on the markers comes to me in a table - listing an ID for each marker, a location and other information not needed for this purpose. The table of data will have a changing number of markers (ie: just one (MYID), or that plus one other, two or even more 'others'), and it will have multiple entries for the each marker (same ID and location, just the other data is different).

One of the markers ids is the same as "MYID" which I then treat differently, but for the others (if any) I have a function that puts them on my map. And each time the function is called it should move them to their new location data, but I currently don't know how to do that elegantly. So I am presently looking to delete all and recreate them each time the function is called (triggered by each time anything changes). Not so good coding.

```
function updatemap(displaytable,MYID) {  // Update other player locations on map    
   OPN=[]; //reset OPN array
   OPX=[]; //reset OPX array
   OPY=[]; //reset OPY array
   for (var r=0;r<OPLoc.length;r++){
       // Need to remove all OPloc off map first and then re-create them?
   };
   OPLoc=[];
   var q=0;
   for (var p=0; p<displaytable.length; p++){ // for every line of the displaytable 
      if ((!OPN.includes(displaytable[p].id)) && (displaytable[p].id != MYID)){ // ... create a unique other player entry, once only
          OPN.push(displaytable[p].id);
          OPX.push(displaytable[p].lat);
          OPY.push(displaytable[p].lon);
          OPLoc[q] = new L.marker([displaytable[p].lat,displaytable[p].lon], {icon: oplayericon})
             .addTo(mymap)
             .bindPopup(displaytable[p].id + "<br>" + displaytable[p].lat + "," + displaytable[p].lon);
          q++;
      };
   };
//...other code not relevant
};
```

None of the variable/arrays in the function are needed anywhere else for anything - I've just created all this mess to do this one thing. And the arrays are created globally so that they are available next time it's called.

I assume there are functions/capabilities of the array commands that I am just not aware of. Can anyone suggest a better way? please?

Answer (score 0):

well, still not sure it's elegant - but it's functional. Not sure if there are edge cases that I'm not covering - but this appears to work and do what I need. I only use two arrays now (one for the markers and one for the ids so I can keep track of what's active). I tried making a 2D array but that made me sad, so it's two arrays now.

````
   for (var s=0;s<displaytable.length;s++) { // display all other players
    if (OPid.includes(displaytable[s].id)) { //if the player is already on the map, just update location
        OPLoc[OPid.indexOf(displaytable[s].id)].setLatLng([displaytable[s].lat,displaytable[s].lon]);
    } else { // if the player is not MYID and not already on the map, create it
        if (displaytable[s].id != MYID) {
            OPid.push(displaytable[s].id);
            OPLoc[OPid.indexOf(displaytable[s].id)] = new L.marker([displaytable[s].lat,displaytable[s].lon], {icon: oplayericon})
            .addTo(mymap)
            .bindPopup(displaytable[s].id);
            };
    };
   }; 
   for (var r=0;r<OPid.length;r++) { //check if the OPlayer is still active
        var found = false;
        for(var q=0;q<displaytable.length;q++) {
             if (displaytable[q].id == OPid[r]) {
                found = true;
             };
        }; 
        if (!found) { //if the OPlayer id is no longer in the displaytable
            mymap.removeLayer(OPLoc[r]); //remove it from the map
            OPLoc.splice(r,1); //remove it from the OPLoc array
            OPid.splice(r,1); //remove it form the OPid array
        };
   };
    ```
````